# How to change content of Post Body in JMeter HTTP Request

Tags: json, httprequest, jmeter, load-testing

Please forgive my ignorance as I'm a jmeter noob.  My webservice accepts JSON objects so I was able to write a rudimentary test where I create an HTTP Request with a JSON object in the "Post Body" portion of the http request.

Anyway, what I want to do is have the HTTP Request choose a different JSON object from a csv file or some other input mechanism so that I can randomize the types of queries that are being run during the load test.  Is there a way to do this?  The closest is probably using variables (section 4.11 in the user manual) but I have a feeling that's not how variables are used.

A second way I've theorized (although I haven't tried yet since I think the method above is easier) is to create a HTTP Request Default obj with a bunch of HTTP Requests with different JSON objects in them and then use a Random Controller to randomly go thru my multiple HTTP Requests on each pass.

If there's a third way, I'm all ears to learn how to use this tool.  I'll continue to read and possibly experiment with plan B above.  Thanks in advance for any help you can give me.

UPDATE: So I tried the second way and it seems to work.  I had 3 different HTTP requests and the number of times each request gets hit varies from run to run.  I still invite answers from the community since I'd like to see what the pros do for issues similar to mine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have partially answered your question yourself, by saying "csv file or". Here are the specifics.

You will have to use  [CSV data set config](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config)  in your test plan to read data from CSV. In your post body, use the variables read from CSV.

Here is  [a screen cast showing how to use csv data set config.](http://tutorials.kpoint.com/kapsule/gcc-5cc9f26b-b05b-4258-82ef-df275c103167/t/csv-data-set-jmeter-tutorial)

Comment: Thx for the link. I'm still not sure how to use CSV from your video. I'm using JMeter 2.9. In my CSV file, each line is a JSON obj. I didn't have separate values on a line like you did in your video. I copied your video and had a var name for the value from the CSV file. I then put ${var} in HTTP Request "Post Body". However, when I run my test, it claims there's an error. When I paste the whole JSON obj into the "Post Body", it succeeds. Is CSV Data Set config only used for "Parameters" or can I also use it for "Post Body" too? I can paste more info into the question if it helps.

Comment: The tutorial is not the exact answer for your problem. Instead of using the hardcoded JSON in `Post Body`, use variables defined in CSV Data set config.