# How to do simulation of the json file ( Body data) in the jmeter using Http- POST method

Tags: json

My test objective:

Using POST method I have to send the json data but there is an ex. 
A, b, c property in that Json file that need to be updated, so It should consider the different request at application end.

To prepare lot .Json file and provide input to j meter is not a feasible solution. How to simulate the data in the.Json file .

I have tried .config csv method but my packet is not formed by appending csv file values . Kindly help me. How to use the variable method to achieve this

Note : This is not the full .json file . Just part of the body . "Properties": { "AccessToken": "111111111-11111-11111-1111111111", "InstallationId": "E1", "AgentType": "xxx", "AgentId": "Vxxx", "SentDateTime": "2018-07-19-13-50-24-5916045", "SourceDateTimeOfEvent": "2018-07-19T13:50:24.5916045+05:30Z", "DateTimeOfEvent": "2018-07-19T08:06:24.5786045Z" "MachineName": "AS-72" } This three parameter need to be updated with every new POST request SourceDateTimeOfEvent,DateTimeOfEvent,SentDateTime and rest of whole body should remains

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change content of Post Body in JMeter HTTP Request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18859057/how-to-change-content-of-post-body-in-jmeter-http-request)

Comment: This is not solve my problem . I have checked this , in my case the data is configured in csv only get post . But my purpose is just only those three varibale mentioned in the .csv file should get updated and rest of POST data remains same

Comment: @Manish Sapariya can you please help me on this ?

Comment: please edit your question and provide an example. how the json looks like? what data should be changed?

Comment: @Manish Sapariya. It will be helpful if I can get any help on this

Comment: Note : This is not the full .json file . Just part of the body . 
 
  "Properties": {
    "AccessToken": "111111111-11111-11111-1111111111",
    "InstallationId": "E1",
    "AgentType": "xxx",
    "AgentId": "Vxxx",
    "SentDateTime": "2018-07-19-13-50-24-5916045",
    "SourceDateTimeOfEvent": "2018-07-19T13:50:24.5916045+05:30Z",
    "DateTimeOfEvent": "2018-07-19T08:06:24.5786045Z"
    "MachineName": "AS-72"
  }

This three parameter need to be updated with every new POST request
SourceDateTimeOfEvent,DateTimeOfEvent,SentDateTime and rest of whole body should  remains same

Comment: @jorj 2 : Hope this clarifies . Please feel to ask more input if required